# Print structure from STL priority queue C++ (QtCreator)

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have a trouble with printing data from priority queue. This data is structure. How can I print structures from my queue?

Here is my structure:

```
struct pinfo
{
    int p_id;
    char path[50];
    int type;
    int priority;
};
```

Here I tried to print my data:

```
void showpq(priority_queue <pinfo> pQueue)
{
    priority_queue <pinfo> g = pQueue;
    while (!g.empty())
    {
        cout << "\t" << g.top();
        g.pop();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

When I tried to print data I get the error message:

```
main.cpp:23: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const value_type {aka const pinfo}’)
     cout << "\t" << g.top();
```

Comment: How would you print such a struct if it wasn't in a priority queue? Make sure that that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the data being stored in a `priority_queue`. You haven't told the program how to print your `pinfo` type. You need to create an `operator<<` for it, something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, pinfo const& p)
{
    os << p.p_id << ", " << p.path << ", " << p.type << ", " << p.priority;
    // or however you want the members to be formatted
    return os; // make sure you return the stream so you can chain output operations
}
```

Comment: This seems like a different problem - I'd guess you don't know how to structure your code in to **components** (`.h` and `.cpp` files). I'd suggest you work through a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191).

Comment: That is right solution, but not full, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function with the following signature:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&&, const pinfo&);
```

which is known to the compiler when you're piping `g.top()` to `std::cout`. The infix `<<` operator simply invokes this function (or an `operator<<` method of the left-hand-side object). Only a few simple, standard types have an `operator<<` predefined in the standard library - and the rest need custom definitions.